# JAVA: difference between Static method invocation with className and with Object of instance

Tags: java, static

I'm little confused on the calling static methods, any way i know this kind of rule

```
Foo.staticMethod();           //accessing static method.
```

for non-static method we must instantiate the class.

```
Foo person1 = new Foo();   //instantiating
person1.nonStaticMethod();       //accessing non-static method.
```

so all we know that static methods are known among the class so does not give a sens when we call it within the object reference like in [Doc Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)
its say :

```
Note: You can also refer to static methods with an object reference like
instanceName.methodName(args)
but this is discouraged because it does not make it clear that they are class methods.
```

Finally my question is as below:

```
public class Foo{

    static int  x = 10;

    public static void method(){
        System.out.println("ANYTHING TO SHOW !!!!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo object = new Foo();

        object.method(); // ANYTHING TO SHOW !!!!
        Foo.method(); // ANYTHING TO SHOW !!!!

        System.out.println(object.x); // Will display as result 10
        System.out.println(Foo.x); //Also this will display as result 10
    }
}
```

> So why the documentation montioned that static field/method not longer with object ref while is give the same.
>
> ## Note :
>
> I know the uses of static keyword, that give smooth ref into memory which each variable declared once into the memory while is
>   attached to static keyword, also i know very well that static keyword
>   useful for hiding method from overriding when we deal with inheritance.
>   so these not included into my question.

Comment: What's the question here?  Yes, this is the expected behavior, it's just discouraged coding style.

Comment: "Static field/method not longer with object ref " Simply means that the Object is not owning that variable x. It is not an instance variable and is not initialised as a part of that objects instance creation. it is initialised while the class is loaded and are stored in Prem Gen.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ:  No, that's not quite a suitable duplicate.  There are differences between the two, yes, but this isn't asking the difference between a static and an instance method, since the only method in the question *is* static.

Comment: @makoto I got it thanks for info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention...

- If one sees `object.method()`, they assume that `method()` is an *instance* method and requires an instance of `Foo` to be used.
- If one sees `Foo.method()`, they *know* that `method()` is a *static* method and does not require an instance of `Foo` to be used.

This is a code readability issue more than a functional issue, since you demonstrate correctly that the code will work in either scenario.  However, it does make understanding that code harder, since now the developer has to be wary of any other possible use of a static method in that fashion.

Remember:  static methods don't require an instance for a reason.  If you find yourself needing an instance for the method at all, it may be worth reconsidering its design.

Answer (score 0):

Because the local variable x is static.  If it were private, Foo.x wouldn't work and would return an error.  Static methods, variables, etc. can be called by using ClassName.staticThing or by instance.staticThing.  Since the variable x was static, it was able to be called by both object.x and Foo.x.  If x were to be a private variable, Foo.x wouldn't work.